# Best way to emulate fulltext search in a InnoDB/MySQL database using Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, search, innodb

I am building an e-commerce system in the codeigniter php framework which needs a full product search. I have used an InnoDB engine in a MySQL database because of it's advantages like support of foreign keys to enforce referential integrity or row locking instead of table locking, but it doesn't support fulltext indexes :'(

The only problem is I need to search the products table for the site search, so I need an alternative method than fulltext indexes which is also compatible for Codeigniter. Has anyone got any suggestions? I have looked into creating a seperate searchable table and Sphinx but they look confusing :S

**Edit**

After checking with the host, I am unable to use Sphinx as the site is on shared hosting and my hosting provider won't allow installation as it is needs root level privileges and they won't do a system wide install as it is 3rd party and they can't guarantee the security of it.

Comment: If you can afford to have an additional process/daemon for your search engine, I would definitely recommend using sphinx

Comment: @Lepidosteus I am unable to use Sphinx as the site is on shared hosting and my hosting provider won't allow installation as it is needs root level privileges and they won't do a system wide install as it is 3rd party and they can't guarantee the security of it.

Comment: Most other frameworks utilize a separate MyISAM table, containing search keywords or even full texts. For example Magento has some `xxx_flat`-tables for search purposes; TYPO3 does the same thing on `xxx_index`-tables.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running? As of version 5.6.4 InoDB does support full text search:
http://blogs.innodb.com/wp/2011/12/innodb-full-text-search-in-mysql-5-6-4/

Comment: That's a bummer... Maybe you can ask your host if they can put you on another server with a newer version? This happened to me a while ago when the server my site was on didn't support the PHP version I needed. They migrated me free of charge, so it won't hurt to ask!

Comment: Would that involve changing the dns records? Because they currently have a site live on the same domain.

Comment: Not sure about that, I can't recall changing nameserver settings when they migrated my site, but to be sure I'd ask it to the hosting party. Good one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way will be to create an MyISAM table for the text data for the product and run the search queries against it. Then you can rebuild the data in the MyISAM table every day with a cron job, to ensure consistency. Or you can make your models to update the data in the MyISAM table on every update.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you update your MySQL simple.
[InnoDB full-text search (FTS) is finally available in MySQL 5.6.4 release.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-storage-engine.html#idp107829680)

These indexes are physically represented as entire InnoDB tables, which are acted upon by SQL keywords such as the FULLTEXT clause of the CREATE INDEX statement, the MATCH() ... AGAINST syntax in a SELECT statement, and the OPTIMIZE TABLE statement.
From [FULLTEXT Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-table-and-index.html#innodb-fulltext-index)